# How to retrieve the value of "Quotes" in this json format?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to build an app where I can retrieve live Currency values online.
I was using `apilayer` and I successfully retrieved the data I wanted except for the final currency value.
I'm not sure how to read the value inside the "quotes" node.

Jason Result from API:

```
    {
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1514567346,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDPHP":49.950001
  }
}
```

Using this:

```
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest
    Dim res As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim rdr As StreamReader

    req = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=xxKeyRemovedxx&currencies=PHP&format=1"), HttpWebRequest)`
    res = DirectCast(req.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    rdr = New StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream)

    Dim jsonresp As String = rdr.ReadToEnd

    Dim jResuldict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, `Object))(jsonresp)`
    Dim qts = jResuldict.Item("quotes").ToString

    MsgBox(qts)
```

Result is:

```
    {
    "USDPHP":49.950001
  }
```

I wanted to retrieve only the value inside `USDPHP` which is 49.95.
So that I can use that value for conversion.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you only need one thing, parse it instead of trying to deserialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `quotes` is a nested dictionary of name/decimal pairs.  To extract it, you can parse your JSON string to a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchy, pick out the `"quotes"` property with [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm), then deserialize its value with [`JToken.ToObject(of Dictionary(of String, Decimal))()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm).  Having done so you can work with as you would with any dictionary, for instance by looping through its key/value pairs with `For Each`:

```
' Extract and deserialize quotes dictionary
Dim quotes as Dictionary(of String, Decimal) = JToken.Parse(jsonresp) _
    .SelectTokens("quotes") _
    .Select(Function(d) d.ToObject(of Dictionary(of String, Decimal))()) _
    .SingleOrDefault()

' Show quotes to the user
Console.WriteLine(If(quotes.Count = 1, "There is 1 quote: ", string.Format("There are {0} quotes", quotes.Count)))
For Each pair in quotes
    Dim name as String = pair.Key
    Dim quote as Decimal = pair.Value

    Console.WriteLine("   Quote for {0} is {1}.", name, quote)
Next
```

Which outputs

> ```
> There is 1 quote: 
>    Quote for USDPHP is 49.950001.
> ```

If you are sure that one and only one `"quotes"` token will be present, you can simplify that a bit by using [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) rather than `SelectTokens()`:

```
' Extract and deserialize quotes dictionary
Dim quotes as Dictionary(of String, Decimal) = JToken.Parse(jsonresp) _
    .SelectToken("quotes") _
    .ToObject(of Dictionary(of String, Decimal))()
```

Finally, if you happen to know the name `USDPHP` in advance you can pick out its specific value with `SelectToken()` then cast it to `Decimal` with an [explicit cast](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_23.htm):

```
Dim quote as Decimal = CType(JToken.Parse(jsonresp).SelectToken("quotes.USDPHP"), Decimal)
```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QlzTSA).

Comment: Thanks, it appears I have so much to learn. Actually, this is my 1st day of learning JSON parsing.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry - glad to help.  I added a third option in case you happen to know the name `USDPHP` in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i have not tested it but it should work

```
Dim qts = jResuldict.Item("quotes.USDPHP").ToString
MsgBox(qts)
```

Comment: Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary. Seems the item Im trying to find is not existing.